# Index Error On Split

Tags: c#

I'm not sure the best way to fix this, in my code:

```
var correctedUrl = Helpers.CorrectUrl(eLink);
string[] splitAndCheckExtension = correctedUrl.Split('.');

if ((Helpers.returnExtensionsAvailable(splitAndCheckExtension[1].ToString()) == true))
{
```

This part: `splitAndCheckExtension[1].ToString()` is just a URLs extension (e.g. .com/.net etc).

The error is: Index was outside the bounds of the array this only happens when malformed URLs are entered like: http://www.www.intera for example.

Function code:

```
public static bool returnExtensionsAvailable(string extension)
{
    string[] ex = new string[] { "com", "com.pl", "net", "org", "pl", "info", "de", "ca", "co.uk", extension};
    if (ex.Contains(extension))
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Please post value of `correctedUrl` when error happens (probably it also would mean you'd have to close the question...)

Comment: Why do you add the `extension` string to `ex`? Your if check is always true then.

Comment: `http://www.www.intera` isn't a malformed URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you should check `splitAndCheckExtension.Length` before using `splitAndCheckExtension[1].ToString()` because it might contain only zero or one elements, in which case `[1]` is outside the bounds of the array.

That said, your code appears to work just fine using the example URL that you provided (https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nyu1aq). If the URL doesn't contain any `.` characters, then you get the index out of bounds exception, as expected.

To fix this, change your `if` statement to something like the following:

```
if (splitAndCheckExtension.Length > 1 &&
    (Helpers.returnExtensionsAvailable(splitAndCheckExtension[1].ToString()) == true))
```